# Wondering about domain types

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain

This may sound like a noob question, but I was playing with Windows Server, and setting up a "domain".

During the set up it asks for a fully qualified domain name. I'm not entirely sure what to put here. Is this a domain that needs to be registered through a domain registrar, or is this something completely different?

Comment: Just name it something like mydomain.local switching the mydomain to whatever you want. Since it is for testing purposes only. If you were to host a real AD implementation they say it is best to register with a top level domain, a.k.a .org, .com, etc.

Comment: Another discussion about similar topic with some helpful links. http://serverfault.com/questions/71052/choosing-local-versus-public-domain-name-for-active-directory

Comment: Thanks. While testing is it possible to join and leave the domain whenever I want with the client machine? Like, can I still log in to my local machine account without logging in to the domain?

Comment: you can select the domain a login and localhost is one of the options. you can also remove the machine from the domain whenever you like, though it takes a minute or two and you need to reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Domains and DNS Domains (Internet) are entirely different, but there is some overlap in that an MS domain establishes a DNS domain as well. MS domains are all about organizing computers and users, their privileges, configurations, etc.

you do not need to register a MS domain with anyone, and you certainly wouldn't want to put your domain on public webspace, so I assume you are using a private IP range like 10.x.y.z, 172.16.y.z, or 192.168.x.y on your local network.